# ¿Por que al hacer un GET de una imagen con Storage, se corrompe?

Tags: php, laravel

Trabajo actualmente en una API en laravel 9 y php 8.1, cuento con una ruta que crea un archivo ZIP y añade a este imágenes PNG y posteriormente retorna el archivo para su descarga, en seguida la función:

```
    ob_end_clean();//Colocado al inicio de la funcion

    // Crear un nuevo archivo zip
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zipFileName = 'files.zip';
    $zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
    
    // Agregar los archivos al archivo zip
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($filesPaths); $i++) {
        $imageData = Storage::get($filesPaths[$i]); //Devuelve el archivo corrompido
        $zip->addFromString($fileNames[$i], $imageData);
    }
    
    // Cerrar el archivo zip
    $zip->close();
    
    // Descargar el archivo zip
    return response()->download($zipFileName)->deleteFileAfterSend();
```

Yo genero las imagenes (correctamente) y las guardo el storage de laravel, el problema aqui es que al aplicar un `Storage::get($path_file)` la imagen me la devuelve corrompida, ya que al descargar y descomprimir el ZIP me indica al abrir la imagen un "Formato incompatible".

(Aclaracion)
Tengo otra ruta el cual descarga la imagen directamente, y me la descarga correctamente solo si aplico `ob_end_clean();` al principio de la funcion, esta solucion la mire en otro [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329299/laravel-file-downloaded-from-storage-folder-gets-corrupted)

Volviendo a la funcion donde creo el ZIP, coloque el `ob_end_clean();` ya que si lo lo hago el ZIP se corrompe.

Gracias.

Comment: no sería más fácil hacer `$zip->addFile($filesPaths[$i], $fileNames[$i]);`